# Id_token missing in RingCentral /token API response

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, ringcentral

I have created application in RingCentral using developer account and calling the authorize and token API to use OpenID Connect flow.

While calling the `/token` API, it is returning only `access_token` but not `id_token`. My application is failing while trying to fetch `id_token` from `/token` API's response. Other OpenId Connect IdP's are working properly. Please find my application details below.

- Platform_type : Server/Web
- Authorization Flows : Authorization Code | Refresh Access Token
- Redirect URI is configured properly.

Please advice?

Thanks & Regards,
Vijeesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RingCentral `/token` endpoint does not return the OpenID Connect `id_token` property, because OpenID Connect is not supported at present, only OAuth 2.0.

OpenID Connect is an identity layer on top of OAuth 2.0 per the specification:

> OpenID Connect 1.0 is a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol.

- Ref: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html

The relevant specification for the RingCentral `/token` endpoint is IETF RFC-6749 section 4.1.4. Access Token Response:

- RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.4